# Путь установки эмуляторов AVD manager

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

Добрый день! Только начинаю изучать разработку приложений на Android Studio и уже существенные проблемы, о которых не говорится на многих обучающих ресурсах. Установил, создаю приложение и тут же возникают ошибки. К сожалению, в моем прошлом вопросе никто так и не ответил как решить, пробую самостоятельно( Есть подозрения, что одна из проблем в пути установки эмуляторов (наличие папки с названием на кириллице). Подскажите: можно ли изменить путь установки эмуляторов (который изначально находиться в файлах пользователя)? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

Можно перенести уже имеющиеся эмуляторы. В папке  с эмуляторами (*профильПользователя/.android/avd*) есть файл "`НазваниеЭмулятора.ini`". Нужно открыть его простым текстовым редактором и изменить содержание строчки `path` (обычно вторая).

Было:

```
 avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
 path=C:\Users\Имяпользователя\.android\avd\Pixel_2_API_26.avd
 path.rel=avd\Pixel_2_API_26.avd 
 target=android-26
```

Стало (например):

```
 avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
 path=C:\avd\Pixel_2_API_26.avd
 path.rel=avd\Pixel_2_API_26.avd 
 target=android-26
```

После этого можно перенести папку с эмулятором по новому адресу.

Придется сделать для каждого эмулятора.

Еще можно создать системную переменную окружения **ANDROID_SDK_HOME**. Тогда, вроде бы, и новые эмуляторы сразу по указанному адресу будут создаваться, но такой путь я не пробовал.

Comment: Все сделал, но теперь студия не видит эти эмуляторы. Как дать понять студии, что они в другом месте?

Comment: Странно как-то. В первый раз после изменения пути все запускается, а потом нет.

Comment: а не подскажете аналогичную среду разработки без многочисленных ошибок под Android вместо Android Studio? А то уже как 3 месяца не могу начать разработку, потому что даже не загружается первая программа(

Answer (score 1):

Тоже долго мучался с этим вопросом. В итоге все получилось.

1. Нужно задать два параметра ANDROID_SDK_HOME и ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
   в параметрах текущего пользователя.
2. в ini файлах изменить путь на новый.
   Вначале была AndroidStudio 3.5, потом обновился на Bumblebee 2021.1.1
   все работает. Смотрите картинки.
   [image: Настройки переменных среды]
   [image: Настройки эмулятора]

Answer (score 0):

**Есть 2 способа:**

**1.** Изменить переменную ANDROID_SDK_HOME, после чего необходимо будет перенести всю папку **.android** из стандартной папки *"C:\Users\Пользователь"* в новую, указанную в ANDROID_SDK_HOME.

**2.** Не изменяя переменную ANDROID_SDK_HOME, указать новый путь для самого образа эмулятора в файле *"C:\Users\Пользователь.android\avd\НазваниеЭмулятора.ini"* в значении **path**. Тогда необходимо будет лишь перенести папку *"C:\Users\Пользователь.android\avd\НазваниеЭмулятора.avd"* в новую директорию, указанную в **path**

Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](http://blog.nagaychenko.com/2011/06/28/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-android-virtual-device/)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не хотите менять переменные среды, можно для каждого вновь созданного (но ещё ни разу не запускавшегося) эмулятора прописать путь (как сказано выше: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/817882/181471) - тогда при первом запуске нового эмулятора его образ сразу будет размещен в указанном каталоге.

P.S. Пишу в виде ответа, поскольку на русском SO я ещё не могу оставлять комментарии и мою правку к вышеуказанному ответу отклонили.